# Is there a way to ignore a base type/class by namespace in Fluent NHibernate automapping?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, automapping

Currently, I am using the following code to ignore base types with Fluent NHibernate automapping:

```
AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Class1>(new MyDefaultAutomappingConfiguration())
            .Conventions.Setup(GetConventions())
            .IgnoreBase<MyCore.BaseTypes.AmazingBaseType>()
            .IgnoreBase<MyCore.BaseTypes.AnotherAmazingBaseType>()
            .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<AutoPersistenceModelGenerator>();
```

Is there a way to ignore base types by a namespace (i.e. `MyCore.BaseTypes`) instead of having to use the `IgnoreBase()` method for every base type I have?

I tried accomplishing this using my overriden `ShouldMap(Type)` method in `DefaultAutomappingConfiguration`-extended class (i.e. `MyDefaultAutomappingConfiguration`) to accomplish this but it still tried to map the base types:

```
public class MyDefaultAutomappingConfiguration: DefaultAutomappingConfiguration {
    public override bool ShouldMap(Type type) {
        return !IsBaseType(type);
    }

    private bool IsBaseType(Type type) {
        return type.Namespace == typeof(MyCore.BaseTypes).Namespace;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What does your `MyAutomappingConfiguration` look like? You can override `ShouldMap(Type)` with something like:

```
public override bool ShouldMap(System.Type type)
{
  return 
    type.BaseType.Namespace == typeof (MyCore.BaseTypes.BaseIWant).Namespace;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your base types are abstract they wont be included in the mapping.

Comment: it seems like it's still trying to map them for some reason because I see them showing up in my conventions...

Comment: Thats strange. Fluent wiki basically says it shouldn't be included unless you specifically tell it to be included. http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping#Abstract_base-classes

Answer (score 1):

You can do it directly in your configuration like this:

```
AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Class1>(new MyDefaultAutomappingConfiguration())
            .Conventions.Setup(GetConventions())
            .Where(t => t.Namespace != "MyCore.BaseTypes")
            .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<AutoPersistenceModelGenerator>();
```

Comment: so is this the only way to do this?

Comment: I don't know if it's the only way but it's the most common and straight forward method. That's what I use anyway :)

Comment: i'm marking this is as the answer. i couldn't get the change to the ShouldMap() method my AutomappingConfiguration to work.

Comment: actually, i marked this as the answer too hastily... i get a runtime error that tells me you can't use the Where method in conjunction with AutomappingConfiguration...

Comment: well, the Where was the way to do it up until recently. I used it in several projects in the past. It seems like ShouldMap replaces it as the way to go in the recent FNH release.

Comment: Here's a post from James Gregory announcing the change: http://fluentnhibernate.org/blog/2010/05/23/feature-focus-automapping.html